# What do the "features enabled" in GNU find mean?

Tags: find, gnu

When I use `find --version` with GNU find, I get something like this:

```
find (GNU findutils) 4.5.9     
[license text]
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS(FTS_CWDFD) CBO(level=2)
```

What do these "features" mean? There's some reference to `O_NOFOLLOW` being a security measure in `man find`, and there's a mention of `LEAF_OPTIMISATION` being an optimization that saves a few `lstat` calls on leaf nodes. But I can't find anything about `FTS`, `D_TYPE` or `CBO`.

Comment: This seems to be the end of the ladder. Maybe could could force someone to read find's source code. Promise some chocolates.

Answer (score 8):

This is a complete answer derived from the answers of Ketan and daniel kullman, as well as my own research.

Most of the "features" turn out to be query optimizations, since `find` is in general capable of (almost) arbitrarily complex queries on the filesystem.

---

### D_TYPE

The presence of the `D_TYPE` feature means that `find` was compiled with support for the `d_type` field in `struct dirent`. This field is a BSD extension also adopted by Linux, which provides the file type (directory, file, pipe, socket, char/block device, etc.) in the structure returned from `readdir` and friends. As an optimization, `find` can use this to reduce or eliminate `lstat` calls when `-type` is used as a filter expression.

`readdir` may not always populate `d_type` on some filesystems, so sometimes an `lstat` will still be needed.

More info from the official documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/d_005ftype-Optimisation.html

### O_NOFOLLOW

This option will read either `(enabled)` or `(disabled)`. If present and enabled, this feature implements a security measure that protects `find` from certain TOCTTOU race attacks. Specifically, it prevents `find` from traversing a symlink while performing directory traversal, which could occur if the directory were replaced by a symlink after the directory's filetype was checked but before the directory was entered.

With this option enabled, `find` will use `open(..., O_NOFOLLOW)` on the directory to open only real directories, then use `openat` to open files within that directory.

### LEAF_OPTIMISATION

This slightly obscure optimization allows `find` to deduce which subdirectories of a parent directory are directories by using the link count of the parent directory, since subdirectories will contribute to the link count of the parent (via the `..` link). In certain circumstances, it will allow `find` to elide a `stat` call. However, if the filesystem or OS misrepresents `st_nlinks`, it may cause `find` to produce bogus results (this is thankfully a very rare occurrence).

More info in the official documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Leaf-Optimisation.html

### FTS

When enabled, the `FTS` feature causes `find` to use the [`fts`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fts.3.html) API to traverse the file hierarchy, instead of a straight recursive implementation.

It's not clear to me what the advantage of `fts` is, but `FTS` is basically the default on all default `find` versions I've seen so far.

More info: https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/fts.html, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fts.3.html

### CBO

It turns out (after reading the `find` source code as suggested by daniel kullman) that "CBO" refers to the query optimization level (it stands for "cost-based optimizer"). For example, if I do `find -O9001 --version`, I get

```
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS() CBO(level=9001)
```

Looking at the `-O` option in `man find`, I see

> ```
> -Olevel
>   Enables query optimisation.   The find program reorders tests to speed up execution  while  preserving  the  overall
>   effect; that is, predicates with side effects are not reordered relative to each other.  The optimisations performed
>   at each optimisation level are as follows.
>
>   0      Equivalent to optimisation level 1.
>
>   1      This is the default optimisation level  and  corresponds  to  the  traditional  behaviour.   Expressions  are
>          reordered  so that tests based only on the names of files (for example -name and -regex) are performed first.
>
>   2      Any -type or -xtype tests are performed after any tests based only on the names  of  files,  but  before  any
>          tests  that  require information from the inode.  On many modern versions of Unix, file types are returned by
>          readdir() and so these predicates are faster to evaluate than predicates which need to stat the file first.
>
>   3      At this optimisation level, the full cost-based query optimiser is enabled.  The order of tests  is  modified
>          so  that  cheap  (i.e. fast) tests are performed first and more expensive ones are performed later, if neces-
>          sary.  Within each cost band, predicates are evaluated earlier or later according to whether they are  likely
>          to  succeed or not.  For -o, predicates which are likely to succeed are evaluated earlier, and for -a, predi-
>          cates which are likely to fail are evaluated earlier.
>
>   The cost-based optimiser has a fixed idea of how likely any given test is to succeed.  In some cases the probability
>   takes  account of the specific nature of the test (for example, -type f is assumed to be more likely to succeed than
>   -type c).  The cost-based optimiser is currently being evaluated.   If it does not actually improve the  performance
>   of find, it will be removed again.  Conversely, optimisations that prove to be reliable, robust and effective may be
>   enabled at lower optimisation levels over time.  However, the default behaviour (i.e. optimisation level 1) will not
>   be  changed  in  the 4.3.x release series.  The findutils test suite runs all the tests on find at each optimisation
>   level and ensures that the result is the same.
> ```

Mystery solved! It's a little strange that the option is a runtime value; usually I would expect the `--version` output only to reflect compile-time options.

Answer (score 1):

Information about `O_NOFOLLOW` is given in the `info` page of `find`:

> 9.2.1.1 O_NOFOLLOW
>
> ..................
>
> If your system supports the O_NOFOLLOW flag (1) to the `open(2)' system
>   call,`find' uses it when safely changing directory.  The target
>   directory is first opened and then `find' changes working directory
>   with the`fchdir()' system call.  This ensures that symbolic links are
>   not followed, preventing the sort of race condition attack in which use
>   is made of symbolic links.
>
> ...

From the source tree, `CBO` occurs only in the file `parser.c`:

```
 printf("CBO(level=%d) ", (int)(options.optimisation_level));
```

indicating it to be cost based optimization (my best guess).

`D_TYPE` occurs at several places in the source-tree and seems like has to do with the directory entry type:

```
$ grep 'D_TYPE' */**
```

Yields:

```
find/parser.c:#if defined USE_STRUCT_DIRENT_D_TYPE && defined HAVE_STRUCT_DIRENT_D_TYPE
lib/savedirinfo.c:#if defined HAVE_STRUCT_DIRENT_D_TYPE && defined USE_STRUCT_DIRENT_D_TYPE
```

and some more entries. You can find the source [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/findutils).

Answer (score 0):

When looking through the findutils source tree (http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/), I found the following:

- configure.ac: --enable-d_type-optimization,Make use of the file type data returned in struct dirent.d_type by readdir()),
- m4/withfts.m4: --without-fts Use an older mechanism for searching the filesystem, instead of using fts()

I didn't find anything about CBO; you might have to download the source code and search for the term..